# How to know github repository linked to azure function for continuous deployment

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-functions, continuous-deployment

I have followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment) to setup Continuous deployment for Azure Functions. Now I have succesffuly setup github repository in Azure function for continuous deployment.

As I am multiple Azure functions each associated with different github branch. Now I want to know which Github repository and branch is linked with particular Azure function

How can I get that information?

Update 1:-

I need to link different git-hub branch for different function apps.

When I goto deployment options after I configured the continuous deployment. Then I see a list of commits pushed to respective branch. But I want to know which repository + branch is linked to the particular function app. Where can I see that information?

[image]

Comment: You can still see this in the `Deployment options` blade inside the Azure Portal, but I don't think this information is (or should be) stored inside GitHub. GitHub only provides webhooks to where certain services (like the CD tooling) can work with. However, I'd like to know as to why you decided using branches for different Azure Functions might be a good idea? Sounds like multiple solutions/projects/repositories might make more sense (IMO)

Comment: You cannot link individual Functions to different repos. Instead, all this happens at the Function **App** level. If you want to deploy form multiple repos, you need multiple Function Apps.

Comment: @Jan_V Refer my updated question.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Refer my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, you could use [kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) to check the `D:\home\site\repository` folder and find the `config` file under the `.git` folder, then you could retrieve the endpoint of your configured repository as follows:

[image]

[image]

Moreover, for your chose branch, you could check the `settings.xml` file under the `D:\home\site\deployments` path.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which branch is used for deployment you can use the Kudu environment for this.

Head down to https://[yourUrl].scm.azurewebsites.net/

From over here you can access the REST API. The `Settings` endpoint contains the information you want.
https://[yourUrl].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings

By navigating to this endpoint you will receive some JSON where a field called `deployment_branch` is populated with the branch you are using for deployment

```
{
    "deployment_branch": "master",
    // Other stuff        
}
```

To check the repository, if you are already inside the Kudu portal, you could try the following:

```
D:\home\site\repository>git remote -v
```

Feels a bit hacky, but it's a way to retrieve the repository remotes (origin).
Not something I would recommend in doing though. Searching for some better way, but this is all for now.

It might be this is the only way to do it, as the documentation states the[following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-continuous-deployment):

> App Service creates an association with the selected repository, pulls in the files from the specified branch, and maintains a clone of your repository for your App Service app. When you configure VSTS continuous deployment from the Azure portal, the integration uses the App Service Kudu deployment engine, which already automates build and deployment tasks with every git push. You do not need to separately set up continuous deployment in VSTS. After this process completes, the Deployment options app blade will show an active deployment that indicates deployment has succeeded.

Still, take in consideration [@David Ebbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111888/david-ebbo)'s comment and use multiple repositories for different functions if you need this kind of granularity.

Comment: Yeah I see branch name when I goto /api/settings. 1. Why I don't see a github repository name in that response? Without repository name, I don't know from which repository it is configured? 2. Is there other way to know this other than REST URL?

Comment: Oh sorry, forget to check the repository location. Sadly I do not know if this can be found easilly when working with the `Deployment option`. You could, of course, search in the filesystem via Kudu and check the `config` file in the `.git` folder, which is located in the `/site/deployments/` folder, but that's not a very nice approach IMO.